# Media player error with prepare() when change orientation android

Tags: android, media-player

I have a problem with media player in Android. I have mp4 file on sd card and want to play it in surfaceview. This is code how I prepare media player:

```
    File file = new File(path);             FileInputStream fis = new
 FileInputStream(file);             mp.setOnCompletionListener(onComplete);
            if (mp != null)
                mp.reset();

            mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());

            mp.setDisplay(holder);          mp.prepare();

            mp.start();
```

Everyting is ok and can play movie, but when I start change orientation always after 4 times I get error with prepare(). I don't know why this error show only when I change orientation 4 times. I don't loose any data, i check on Debug Any idea?

Comment: make your AndroidManifest.xml handle screen orientation and screen size changes

Comment: This is not problem with orientation, because this work first three times when orientation is chenging

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

try{
          File file = new File(path);             FileInputStream fis = new
                  FileInputStream(file);            mp.setOnCompletionListener(onComplete);
                             if (mp != null)
                             mp.reset();

                           mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());

                             mp.setDisplay(holder);          mp.prepare();

                            mp.start();
}catch(Exception e){

    }
```